# My app is installed in emulator, but throws an error : Unfortunately AppNAME has stopped

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

I am building an app using Phonegap and Cordova. When I run the app in Eclipse emulator the **apk** gets installed successfully but after clicking on it I get an alert saying "**Unfortunately AppName has Stopped**" Any guidance or suggestion to solve this problem will be great, thanks.

**Console:**

```
[2013-11-13 12:18:47 - Challenger] Dx 
trouble writing output: already prepared
[2013-11-13 12:18:48 - Challenger] ------------------------------
[2013-11-13 12:18:48 - Challenger] Android Launch!
[2013-11-13 12:18:48 - Challenger] adb is running normally.
[2013-11-13 12:18:48 - Challenger] Performing com.disciplinexgames.DisciplineXgames.Challenger activity launch
[2013-11-13 12:18:48 - Challenger] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'testDevice'
[2013-11-13 12:18:48 - Challenger] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'testDevice'
[2013-11-13 12:18:57 - Challenger] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-11-13 12:18:57 - Challenger] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2013-11-13 12:19:55 - Challenger] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-11-13 12:19:55 - Challenger] Uploading Challenger.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-11-13 12:20:09 - Challenger] Installing Challenger.apk...
[2013-11-13 12:21:33 - Challenger] Success!
[2013-11-13 12:21:33 - Challenger] Starting activity com.disciplinexgames.DisciplineXgames.Challenger on device emulator-5554
[2013-11-13 12:21:34 - Challenger] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.disciplinexgames.DisciplineXgames/.Challenger }
```

**LogCat:**

```
11-13 07:21:36.140: D/AndroidRuntime(837): Shutting down VM
11-13 07:21:36.140: W/dalvikvm(837): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
11-13 07:21:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(837): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 07:21:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(837): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.disciplinexgames.DisciplineXgames/com.disciplinexgames.DisciplineXgames.Challenger}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.disciplinexgames.DisciplineXgames.Challenger" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.disciplinexgames.DisciplineXgames-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.disciplinexgames.DisciplineXgames-1, /system/lib]]
11-13 07:21:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
11-13 07:21:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
11-13 07:21:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-13 07:21:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-13 07:21:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-13 07:21:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-13 07:21:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-13 07:21:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 07:21:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-13 07:21:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-13 07:21:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-13 07:21:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 07:21:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(837): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.disciplinexgames.DisciplineXgames.Challenger" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.disciplinexgames.DisciplineXgames-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.disciplinexgames.DisciplineXgames-1, /system/lib]]
11-13 07:21:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
11-13 07:21:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
11-13 07:21:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
11-13 07:21:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
11-13 07:21:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
11-13 07:21:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  ... 11 more
```

**androidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0.0" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.disciplinexgames.DisciplineXgames" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="Challenger" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: It seems that Android cannot find a class or a library that it need it on runtime. com.disciplinexgames.DisciplineXgames.Challenger ?

Comment: Ensure that cordova.jar is present in libs folder.

Comment: add proper app name on androidMainfest.xml

Comment: @AmitPrajapati in manifest I currently i have <application android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

Should I change it to app_name to DisciplineXgames

Comment: Add your ComponentInfo activity in manifest file.

Comment: @RupeshNerkar can you give me an example please ?

Comment: <activity
            android:label="LabalName"
            android:name=".Activityname" >
        </activity> in <application></application>

Comment: I did this but the problem still remains the same :(

Comment: code contains any network related oprations...?

Comment: by network related if you mean Internet than yes. Its built using AJAX as a backend.

Answer (score 0):

ClassNotFoundException. Your app is unable to find your class. check your all java files once. or post your manifest file.

Comment: Make sure your manifest file and activity has same class name

Comment: Please check the ques again, I have just added my manifest file code in the ques.

Comment: android:name="Challenger". First check your activity name, is should be "Challenger". if it is challenger then put . before Challenger. So it will looks like android:name=".Challenger".

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order & Export and ensure Android Private Libraries are checked for your project and for all other library projects you are using. Clean all projects afterwards and see what happens.

Comment: I just checked it they are checked!

Comment: I didn't wrote any Java code. I am using phonegap library which means I have coded it in HTML, CSS and JS and not core java

Comment: @colourtheweb  ohh sorry i dnt have idea about PhoneGap. I think you are facing this problem due to mismatching of either package name or class name in menifest.xml and wherever you import your package name. 
So please cross check it

Answer (score 0):

Is it displaying the error when you click a button?

Comment: when I click OK after that nothing happens. All these error comes when I launch the application in the emulator.

Comment: There are many reasons why this could be happening.for me, this happens when i place my code for Handling button press event in the onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){...} method instead of the onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){...} method...try moving your event handling code to the onCreateOptionsMenu() method and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid mixing upper- and lowercase-names in packagenames, it is destined for trouble. Especially if you are developing on a windows-machine.

So, instead of the package-name com.disciplinexgames.DisciplineXgames use com.disciplinexgames.disciplinexgames by renaming the package-directory and replacing the packagename in every file of your project.